# How to set custom field values in Account for Lead conversion?

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I'm trying to use Database.LeadConvert to set Account fields based on a condition, as such:

```
 Database.LeadConvert lc= new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(lead.Id);
        lc.setConvertedStatus('Closed-Converted');
        lc.accountrecord.CustomField = 'Value';
        Database.leadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
```

However I get a "Variable does not exist: CustomField" Error in the second to last line.

How would I go about achieving the task using Database.LeadConvert class?

Huge thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [doc for `LeadConvert`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_dml_convertLead.htm) class, you can see there is no property to allow specification of values on the converted-to Account, Contact, or Opportunity records.

At best you have `setAccountId(id)` which mimics the UX where the user can choose to use an existing accountId

The pattern you want to use are the Lead Mapping rules (`Setup | Object Manager | Lead | Fields`) that allow you to map fields on the Lead object to custom fields on the Account, Contact, and Opportunity objects

These Lead fields can be formulas or hidden-from-page layout.

In your example, you might have a formula field on Lead called `Account_Custom_Field_X__c` which has the desired value and you use the Lead Mapping rules to:

```
Lead                              Account
Account_Custom_Field_X__c   =>    Custom_Field_X__c
```